# Are [INST] and [/INST] needed for mistral chat?

Tags: nlp, mistral-7b

On the page [Open-weight models](https://docs.mistral.ai/models/), they use [INST] and [/INST] in the template. (If I understood correctly, they fined tuned the basic text completion model on a dataset of instructions with the format `<s>[INST] Instruction [/INST] Model answer</s>[INST] Follow-up instruction [/INST]` so that you can "turn on/off" the instruction mode.)

However, in the [guide](https://docs.mistral.ai/guides/basic-RAG/) for RAG, they do not use these special tokens, so I am confused about whether they are necessary. Is the instruct model being used or is there another model fined tuned on chat messages?

I found this page [Fine-tuning Mistral 7B for chat](https://mistral.ai/news/announcing-mistral-7b/), which suggests that the instruct model can be used for chat.

> To show the generalization capabilities of Mistral 7B, we fine-tuned
> it on instruction datasets publicly available on HuggingFace. No
> tricks, no proprietary data. The resulting model, Mistral 7B Instruct,
> outperforms all 7B models on MT-Bench, and is comparable to 13B chat
> models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mistral got two different models, Mistral-7B and Mistral-7B-Instruct.The Mistral-7B-Instruct is fine-tuned for conversation and question answering. For Instruct you need to put [INST] and  same as you already mentioned. But for Mistral-7B you can give any format and it will try to generate. Also, if you are using transformers library you can use apply_chat_template (https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/chat_templating).

for more details about mistral, you can visit https://www.promptingguide.ai/models/mistral-7b